# How to make it so that when you scroll over a button a menu appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

On my front page next to my read more link under my posts I want to add a social share menu. However I only want the share menu to appear when a user hovers over a share button.  Similar to the images below. I have added all of the menu links and the initial share button. However, I can't figure out how to make the menu appear when you hover over button. Does anyone have any solutions? here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wow3820z/

share button

[image]

share button on hover (shows social share menu)

[image]

my social share html

```html
<div class="share-buttons">

<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Love this post by @ <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="https://www.theclimategroup.org/sites/all/modules/custom/tcg_social_media_icons/icons/black/16x16/twitter.png"></a>
   
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.shipwreckmuseum.com/wp-content/themes/shipwreckmuseum/assets/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>
    
 <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FaD4j4FL1Bc/TuEf9aN1gEI/AAAAAAAABek/kVqztZRwJ1w/s128/Pinterest_Favicon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
    </a>
    
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.ihatestevensinger.com/osafe_theme/images/user_content/images/icon-heart.png" alt="Heart" />
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in a container/wrapper, hide the share buttons, and when you hover over the wrapper, show the share buttons.

```css
.wrap:hover .share-buttons {
  display: block;
}
.share-buttons {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <img class="main-share button" src="http://amandoblogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/share-e1408475480528.png" />

  <div class="share-buttons">

    <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Love this post by @ <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="https://www.theclimategroup.org/sites/all/modules/custom/tcg_social_media_icons/icons/black/16x16/twitter.png"></a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.shipwreckmuseum.com/wp-content/themes/shipwreckmuseum/assets/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
      <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FaD4j4FL1Bc/TuEf9aN1gEI/AAAAAAAABek/kVqztZRwJ1w/s128/Pinterest_Favicon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
    </a>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://www.ihatestevensinger.com/osafe_theme/images/user_content/images/icon-heart.png" alt="Heart" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works however the menu will show up even if you scroll somewhat close to the main share button. You see what I mean? You can be a good ways away from the main share button and the menu will still appear. I want the social share menu to show up only if you scroll over the area of the button. Is that possible?

Comment: Also - I put this social button next to two other buttons. I want it so that this social button will always stay next to the other two buttons and then when you hover over the social button the social share menu appears underneath. If you take a look at this fiddle you can see the social share button goes above the other two buttons and the social share menu is next to the other two buttons? - https://jsfiddle.net/5mgoktLs/1/

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle.

on the html

```
<div class="share-buttons" id='sharebuttons' style='display:none'>

<a id="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=Love this post by @ <?php the_title(); ?> - <?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" title="Tweet this!"><img src="https://www.theclimategroup.org/sites/all/modules/custom/tcg_social_media_icons/icons/black/16x16/twitter.png"></a>

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.shipwreckmuseum.com/wp-content/themes/shipwreckmuseum/assets/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>

 <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());">
        <img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-FaD4j4FL1Bc/TuEf9aN1gEI/AAAAAAAABek/kVqztZRwJ1w/s128/Pinterest_Favicon.png" alt="Pinterest" />
    </a>

    <a id='heart' href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.ihatestevensinger.com/osafe_theme/images/user_content/images/icon-heart.png" alt="Heart" />
    </a>

</div>
```

using native javascript

```
var mainsharebutton = document.getElementById('mainsharebutton');

mainsharebutton.addEventListener('mouseover', showMenu);
mainsharebutton.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideMenu);

function showMenu(){
        var myMenu = document.getElementById('sharebuttons');
    myMenu.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideMenu(){
        var myMenu = document.getElementById('sharebuttons');
    myMenu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Basically just added mouse events onmouseover and onmouseleave on your share button, then I display or un-display the buttons div depending on the event triggered